# empty input field before submit

Tags: html, forms, jsp, null

When I am doing form processing, I have a form.html file and a process.jsp file.
the form.html will display the form and action is set to process.jsp.
I need to check whether the user fill in the input field.

```
    <% 
      String name = request.getParameter("name");
      if(name==null||name.length()==0){
          out.println("you need to enter your name.")
      }
     %>
```

what will be the return value of the request.getParameter("name") if the user does not type in any thing and click on the submit button.
Cause I don't know it will be a null value or an empty string so I checked both.
But just want to get an idea whether it is null or an empty string.

Comment: show us your html form code please

Comment: What is your question? Your condition seems logic...

Answer (score 0):

`request.getParameter("name")` returns `null` when the value is not set and `""` when the value is an empty string. Both cases can occur.

Comment: thank you very much. So just to double check, if in the form element, the value attribute is set to "" , then i will get back a "" instead of null value after making use of request.getParameter();

Comment: Exactly. `""` could be perfectly valid input in some scenario.

Comment: It would be nice if you upvote and/or accept the correct/helpful answer(s) to your questions.